# Web2Py MySQL data retrieval

Tags: mysql, web2py

A web2py and python newbie here.

I tried to do a sample web app with MySQL DB as backend DB. I have created a table in MySQL separately and populated with values and I want to display the table values in the UI. I have an error -

"class 'gluon.contrib.pymysql.err.InternalError'> (1050, u"Table '' already exists")"

My config files are below:

db.py

```
if not request.env.web2py_runtime_gae:
    db = DAL('mysql://xxxxx',pool_size=1,check_reserved=['all'])
else:

    session.connect(request, response, db=db)

response.generic_patterns = ['*'] if request.is_local else []


from gluon.tools import Auth, Crud, Service, PluginManager, prettydate
auth = Auth(db)
crud, service, plugins = Crud(db), Service(), PluginManager()

## create all tables needed by auth if not custom tables
auth.define_tables(username=False, signature=False)


## after defining tables, uncomment below to enable auditing
# auth.enable_record_versioning(db)
db.define_table('user_details',
   Field('user_id', 'text'),
    Field('first_name', 'text'),
    Field('last_name', 'text'),
    Field('city', 'text'),
    Field('user_st', 'text'),migrate=True)
```

My home page look like this

```
{{ rows = db(db.user_details).select() }}
{{if len(rows):}}
<ul>
{{ for r in rows: }}
  <li>

        {{=r.name}}

  </li>
{{pass}}
</ul>
{{pass}}
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Any help appreciated, thanks.

---

I got it now. Just had to change migrate=False. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have `migrate=True`, and web2py doesn't have any record that it has already created the table, so it is attempting to create it again. You can get web2py to updates it's records about the table by temporarily setting `fake_migrate=True` (or alternatively, set `migrate=False` and don't let web2py handle migrations).

Also, note that by default, web2py expects every table to include an auto-increment integer field called "id", so you should make sure your table includes such a field. Better yet, if the table is new anyway, don't create it manually in MySQL. Instead, just let web2py create it (it will do so the first time the table definition is run). Once it has been created by web2py, you can then add any records you like.